# Under heavy cache conditions, updating the parent theme don't reflect changes with child theme enabled

Tags: child-theme, cache

I use W3 Total Cache, Cloudflare (and CloudFront for media files).
I use a Child Theme to customize specifically for my site while maintaining the core theme with the parent theme.

Whenever I update the Parent Theme, the changes are not reflected while the Child Theme is the Active Theme.

However, if I re-upload or update the Child Theme's Style.css, it does reflect the new changes. I'm guessing it's the cache.

What do I do, so I don't have to worry about the Child Theme when the updates are with the Parent Theme (while I continue to have the Child Theme as my Active Theme)?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the W3TC plugin while you are still designing the site because the plugin itself suggests to use it once you are completely done with the designing

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *file modification time* (`filemtime`) to trigger a reload (and recache) of the file.

This is how I usually enqueue styles (and scripts):

```
$file = '/css/some-styles.css';
wp_enqueue_style(
    'some-styles',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri().$file,
    array('some-dependency'),
    filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().$file)
);
```

This results in something like the following:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='some-styles-css'
    href='.../css/some-styles.css?ver=1388657898' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

You would have to do this for both the parent and the child theme, though.